# Code to separate the numbers alphabets in a string and print it in a list # if the user gives empty string, then empty list must be printed

Tags: python

Here's my code:

```
# Code to separate the numbers alphabets in a string and print it in a list
# If the user gives empty string, then empty list must be printed

def string_string(string1):
    number=''
    alpha=''
    empty=''

    list1=[]

    for i in (string1):

        if(i>='a' and i<='z' or i>='A' and i<="Z"):
            alpha=alpha+i
        elif(i==1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 or 9 or 0):
            number = number+i
        elif(i== ''):
            list1.append(empty)
        else:
            pass

    list1.append(int(number))
    list1.append(alpha)

    print(list1)

string1 = str(input())
string_string(string1)
```

I want the code to behave as follows:

**Case 1:** (separate letters from numbers) 
Input: `a888rudhvigk` 
Output: `['arudhvigk', 888]`

**Case 2:** (empty string) 
Input:   (empty string) 
Output: `['']`

Comment: You can simplify this a lot by using `isdigit()` and empty-string falseness to pick out the numbers/blanks.

Comment: There can be a lot of ways to simplify your code. but I believe you are a beginner, so let's just fix your existing code: `if number != '': list1.append(int(number))` instead of `list1.append(int(number))` will fix it.

Comment: it is not solving the problem and we should not use built-in methods. case 2 is not satisfying  case2: input: #user gives space as an input output: ['']

Comment: `elif(i==1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 or 9 or 0):` doesn't mean what you think it means (even apart from the fact that a string will never equal an int). It will always evaluate to `True` since `i == 1 or 2 or 3 ...` isn't equivalent to `i == 1 or i == 2 or ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
s = 'a888rudhvigk'
number = ''
string = ''
for i in s:
    if i.isdigit():
        number = number + i
    else:
        string = string + i
lst = [string, number]

output:  ['arudhvigk', '888']
```

Comment: What is "`out ['arudhvigk', '888']`"? Garbled [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-eval-print_loop) session output?

Comment: i meant, this list ['arudhvigk', '888'] is the output of my code, the answer was edited